# Detect regional currency format (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

Okay so I have an app with a numberfield (buttons with values 0-9) that updates a label which is formatted to the local currency.
The label automatically places the decimal for the user, so the format is 0.00.
Now this is a problem because iphone formats most other currencies, such as the Euro, as 0,00.

Is there a way to detect the regional currency format (Settings > International > Region Format)?

I would then make an if statement accordingly.

My current number pad code:

```
NSString *digit = sender.currentTitle;
numberField.text = [numberField.text stringByAppendingString:digit];

NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@""];
[numberFormatter setMaximumIntegerDigits:4];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

numberField.text = [numberField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"."    withString:@""];
NSDecimalNumber *currency = [[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:numberField.text]   decimalNumberByDividingBy: [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"100"]];
numberField.text = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:currency];
```

You can see on line 11 where it inserts the decimal. When i change it to a comma, the 0,00 format works properly.

And the conversion:

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *string = [f stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[numberField.text floatValue]]];

numberField.text=string;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

------------------EDIT------------------

I believe that @lnafziger probably has a more efficient way to do it. In addition to the `NSLocaleDecimalSeparator` key, you might also find the `NSLocaleGroupingSeparator` and `NSLocaleCurrencySymbol` keys useful.

Hope this helps!

You could use:

```
NSString *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier];
if(locale isEqualToString: @"en_US"){

    //Set Device Currency to American Dollars

}
else if(locale isEqualToString: @"fr_FR"){

    //Set Device Currency to Euros

}
else if(locale isEqualToString: @"en_AU"){

    //Set Device Currency to Australian Dollars

}
```

For more info on `NSLocale`, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wow thanks! `NSLocale` is exactly what I'm looking for! Do you know if the value of `NSLocaleDecimalSeparator` is declared? Ex: '.' or the word 'decimal'?

Comment: @David It returns the punctuation (ex. ",").

Comment: Okay i figured it out! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

To get the decimal separator character for the current locale, use this:

```
NSLocale *loc       = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *separator = [loc objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator];
```

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need, but I tried: `if(separator==@"."){numberField.text = [numberField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];}` but it didnt work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can't test string equality with "==". Use -isEqualToString: That is **if ([separator isEqualToString:@"."])**...

Comment: @JoshuaNozzi showed how to properly compare a string like the separator!  You need to use this for all string comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

To get local (from user defined settings) currency US$ or € I use this snippet:

```
NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSString *dec = [f stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.01]];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *string = [f stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.01]];

NSString *currency = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:dec withString:@""];
currency =  [currency stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSLog(@"local currency:%@",currency);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iphone is a *hnu985jmpl895662* way format. 
so the answer to this is; Generation 4 with current discisenables7 . Lol Jk IDK

Answer (score 0):

This converts a number to a local currency string
`[NSNumberFormatter localizedStringFromNumber:dec numberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle]`;